# Custom partitioning with Java kafka client

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I was able to write a kafka sample app in Java. It has 3 topics and pub/sub is working fine. But couldn't assign those topics into different partitions.

**My Consumer**

```
public class Consumers extends Thread {
    private static final List<String> TOPIC_LIST = Arrays.asList("topic1", "topic2", "topic3");
    private static final List<TopicPartition> PARTITION_LIST = 
Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition(TOPIC_LIST.get(0), 1), new TopicPartition(TOPIC_LIST.get(1), 2));

    private void message() {
        Properties consumerProperties = KafkaProperties.getConsumerProperties();
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProperties);
        consumer.assign(PARTITION_LIST);
        Logger.debug("Kafka IP : " + consumerProperties.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    process(record.topic(), record.value());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error("error while consuming : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }

    private void process(String topic, String value) {
        KafkaProcessor.process(topic, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        message();
    }
}
```

**My Custom Partitioner**

```
public class CustomPartitioner implements Partitioner {
private static Map<String, Integer> partitionMap;

@Override
public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    System.out.println("Inside CustomPartitioner.configure " + configs);
    partitionMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : configs.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith("partitions.")) {
            String keyName = entry.getKey();
            String value = (String) entry.getValue();
            int partitionId = Integer.parseInt(keyName.substring(11));
            partitionMap.put(value, partitionId);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
    List partitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);
    String valueStr = (String) value;
    String name = ((String) value).split(":")[0];
    if (partitionMap.containsKey(name)) {
        //If the country is mapped to particular partition return it
        return partitionMap.get(name);
    } else {
        //If no country is mapped to particular partition distribute between remaining partitions
        int noOfPartitions = cluster.topics().size();
        return value.hashCode() % noOfPartitions + partitionMap.size();
    }
}

public void close() {
}}
```

**My Producer**

```
public void producer(String topic, String message) {
    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(KafkaProperties.getProducerProperties());
    try {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, message);
        producer.send(producerRecord);
        producer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("kafka message publish error: ", e);
    }
}
```

When I run this code. I've got following warnings.

```
[warn] o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig - The configuration partitions.2 = partition2 was supplied but isn't a known config.
[warn] o.a.k.c.p.ProducerConfig - The configuration partitions.1 = partition1 was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

My producer properties are as follows,

```
 properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
 properties.put("acks", "all");
 properties.put("retries", 0);
 properties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomPartitioner.class.getCanonicalName());
 properties.put("partitions.1", "partition1");
 properties.put("partitions.2", "partition2");
 properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
 properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

With these properties and code I couldn't send or receive messages. How may I fix this.

Comment: `cluster.topics().size()` is not giving you partitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating partitions is configured through topic config, and not producer configuration. For an existing topic you want:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <ZK_HOST> --alter --topic <TOPIC_NAME> --partitions <NUM_PARTITIONS>
```

Your warnings are quite clear: `partitions.1` and `partitions.2` are not valid properties, and so Kafka is letting you know that it has no idea what to do with them. You should remove those two lines.

More importantly, **you don't need `CustomPartitioner`**. Kafka automatically distributes data across partitions via the hash of the key. So if you add the country as a key to your records:

```
ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, message.split(":")[0], message);
```

then you can guarantee that all data from the same country will go to the same partition, and you can remove your entire `CustomPartitioner` class. Also remove `consumer.assign(PARTITION_LIST);`; again, Kafka manages this for you.

Comment: If one country occurred more frequently than the others, though, then you'd need to account for "hot" partitions, or certain brokers getting all that data. In that event, a custom partitioner is needed, for example, you can round robin that particular  key between multiple brokers, and distribute the rest

Comment: Of course, but in this particular situation then it seems like we're a few steps away from needing to tweak for performance. Walk before you can run, and all that.

Comment: @cricket_007 should I edit my answer to include what you just said, or is your comment the right place for it?

Comment: I think it's fine as a comment. But you're welcome to clarify it. I was just providing an example of when a custom partitioner could be used

Comment: thanks for the support. Now I able to send and receive messages correctly.